# Jest encountered an unexpected token + react markdown

Tags: reactjs, testing, ts-jest, babel-jest, react-tsx

I'm getting an error when trying to run my test file (I'm using react typescript)

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

    Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

    By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.

    Here's what you can do:
     • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
     • If you are trying to use TypeScript, see https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-typescript
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
    For information about custom transformations, see:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation

    Details:

    export {uriTransformer} from './lib/uri-transformer.js'
    ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

       5 | const Markdown = ({ text, classStyle }: ITextMedia) => (
       6 |   <div className={`${classes.mediaParagraph} ${classStyle ?? ''}`}>
    >  7 |     <ReactMarkdown>{text}</ReactMarkdown>
         |                                             ^
       8 |   </div>
       9 | );
      10 | export default Markdown;

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1728:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (components/media/markdown/index.tsx:7:45)
```

I already tried adding the React markdown to the transform ignore patterns, but it still doesn't work

here's my jest.config

```
{
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.js'],
  moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', '<rootDir>/'],
  testEnvironment: 'jest-environment-jsdom',
  moduleNameMapper: {
    'next/router': '<rootDir>/__mocks__/next/router.js',
    '^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$': 'identity-obj-proxy',
    '^.+\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|webp|avif|svg)$': '<rootDir>/__mocks__/file-mock.js',
  },
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(js|jsx)$': 'babel-jest'
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    'node_modules/(?!react-markdown/)'
  ]
}
```

my babel config:

```
{
    "presets": [
        "next/babel",
        "@babel/preset-env"
    ],
    "plugins": []
}
```

I'm new to jest, so I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong

Answer (score 45, accepted):

In the `jest.config` file, you need to add the following to the `moduleNameMapper` attribute:

`"react-markdown": "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-markdown/react-markdown.min.js"`

So effectively, your `moduleNameMapper` should really look like this:

```js
  ...
  moduleNameMapper: {
    'next/router': '<rootDir>/__mocks__/next/router.js',
    '^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$': 'identity-obj-proxy',
    '^.+\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|webp|avif|svg)$': '<rootDir>/__mocks__/file-mock.js',
    'react-markdown': '<rootDir>/node_modules/react-markdown/react-markdown.min.js',
  },
  ...
```

Good luck!

Comment: thank you, that worked for me, can you explain why this step is needed?

Comment: Hi @Anne, the purpose of the `moduleNameMapper` is essentially to stub out resources for the purpose of testing. But sometimes it can also be used to help Jest find the right modules to run tests with. In the case of `react-markdown`, it just needs a little help to point to the right directory to run the right file for the tests. I hope this helps.

Comment: Finally I found this solution working for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The following fix in `jest.config.js` no longer works from version 9.0.0 as they [remove the bundle step](https://github.com/remarkjs/react-markdown/commit/c0dfbd6e09509d9c6e296b8d3d9a8692d3ae1927).

```
  ...
  moduleNameMapper: {
    'react-markdown': '<rootDir>/node_modules/react-markdown/react-markdown.min.js',
  },
  ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add not only `react-markdown` to the `transformIgnorePatterns`, but also all its dependencies which are pure ESM.

When running your tests you can see the dependencies one by one in the jest error. Remember about ones inside `react-markdown` node_modules.

```
Details:

/{...}/node_modules/react-markdown/node_modules/comma-separated-tokens/index.js:23
```

Add one by one in the `transformIgnorePatterns` and run the tests again to get the next error.

You have to add the `react-markdown`, `comma-separated-tokens`, and others. It'll depend on the `react-markdown` version you use. In my case it was:

```
"transformIgnorePatterns": [
  "/node_modules/(?!comma-separated-tokens|space-separated-tokens|hast-util-whitespace|property-information|trim-lines|remark-rehype|remark-parse|trough|is-plain-obj|bail|unified|vfile|react-markdown)"
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Its a simple fix in the code, just change the import statement from

```js
import ReactMarkdown from 'react-markdown';
```

to

```js
import ReactMarkdown from 'react-markdown/react-markdown.min';
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in my environment. We use `nx` in a monorepo and manage our packages with `pnpm`. Since `pnpm` caches modules by default, it does not work with the `<rootDir>/node_modules/`. However, you can also do without this path, then it works with `pnpm` as well (`jest` also mentions in its docs that the usage of `<rootDir>` is optional):

```
…
moduleNameMapper: {
  'react-markdown': 'react-markdown/react-markdown.min.js',
},
…
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I've been trying everything I can for hours. This is the right path forward for me. I have react-markdown included through a 3rd party include

Answer (score 1):

I Recommend this solution only if you want the error to be ignored.

create an empty mock file - (*empty-mock.ts* in relevant folder)

```
const EmptyMock = {};

export default EmptyMock;
```

And map this to import modules to be ignored -

```
const customJestConfig = {
  moduleNameMapper: {
    //imports to be ignored by jest
    "react-markdown": "<rootDir>/mock/empty-mock.ts",
    "remark-gfm": "<rootDir>/mock/empty-mock.ts",
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem for **@uiw/react-markdown-preview** plugin.

The only thing I can do it just add this under **moduleNameMapper** inside package.json

```
"react-markdown-preview": "<rootDir>/node_modules/@uiw/react-markdown-preview/dist/markdown.min.js"
```